# How to... Three wordpress sites with one css .... ? child theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am currently working on a website with three domains 
like

```
en.mydomain.com
ar.mydomain.com
ur.mydomain.com
```

all these sites are running the same theme but with different contents...

i want all of them to use one style.css and rtl.css file so that i don't have to change the same code in three different files .... just one change will effect all of them... I am using child theme in each site .....

> If any of you have some idea on it... please share with me... and save
>   me from a big headache :)
>
> Many thanks :)

Comment: A simple Multisite installation can do it. http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: and these are not 3 different domains, but 3 subdomains

Comment: If all three websites are in the same server you can use a symlink.

Comment: Also, this is off topic here. You should ask in the WordPress forums or on wordpress.stackexchange.com. Voting to close it.

Comment: thanks for your answers... i asked the question here because stock stackoverflow is already having a wordpress tag with  37979 votes ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just link to the same stylesheet(?)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.URL_OF_YOUR_STYLESHEET.css" />
```

Comment: Probably the easiest way. Replace the existing links to css files in the header.php file for each site.

Comment: the styles defined in default css are same now .... but the styles those ware not in default and i added them in my external css are loaded....

Comment: You need to load your css after the default theme css in order to override it